# How can I change the ip address of my network info using terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, terminal

when I put this in the terminal

> ifconfig eth0 69.69.69.69

the ip address in the terminal change but in the user interface not, I mean

**initial state**
my ip is 192.168.10.2

**then a put in the terminal**

> ifconfig eth0 69.69.69.69

and this happens 
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUB34.png)
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOhYh.png)

As we can see the properties didn't change.
what can I do for change that properties using the terminal or a bash?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a Linux distribution that uses the `NetworkManager` daemon, and during installation it decided that eth0 should be configured via DHCP. So every time you manually setup its IP not using it (from a terminal in your case), `NetworkManager` will set it up again without noticing you within a few seconds or minutes.

To check if you have indeed `NetworkManager` running and managing eth0 setup, issue:

> ps aux | grep -i networkmanager

If it is indeed running, look for more info about it, from Ubuntu for instance:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

...and then google around for "network manager manual setup ip".

PS:

I hate `NetworkManager` with a deep passion, gave up using it years ago and always uninstall it, managing my interfaces manually and/or the good old `/etc/network/interfaces` way.  Noticeably (in my case) it can be a pure nuisance when [multihoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) and changing the interface*S* setup frequently. So if this is indeed your problem (90% sure) I can't help you much more with it. `NetworkManager` is good at managing *one interface at a time*, with *one configuration (ex static or DHCP) for each interface*. *This satisfy 95% of user cases.* But not mine.

Answer (score 0):

i have try this in my computer and i have success

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.218.110
```

if you want to chang the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0  to chang the ip.
you can use vim edit chang thhis line:IPADDR=192.168.218.111